# Wygwam 3.1.1 + GWCode syntaxhighlighter 1.0.0 - does this work for anybody?

Tags: wygwam

I am trying to use GWCode syntaxhighlighter plugin with wygwam. I get the [code] icon in the toolbar, but then when I click it, I get a javascript error attempting to open the syntaxhighlight dialog box.

I suspect the problem is that wygwam updated to a newer version of ckeditor and left syntaxhighlighter behind.

(I asked this initially about wygwam 3.0.2, but update to 3.1.1 unfortunately changed nothing)

Answer (score 1):

Answer (with thanks to Brandon for helping me figure it out): no.

I did get it to work by updating GWCode Syntaxhighlighter plugin to the current version of the underlying ckeditor-syntaxhighlight plugin.